# How secure is the flash hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How secure is the flash hash? Can a user easily see the values stored in it and inject his own values?

Comment: I'm not a ruby guy so I can't answer, but let's apply reason: Does it exist in the client-side part of the website? If so, it's available to the client, or at least you should assume it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rails will, by default, store the session in a cookie. The session state is kept in a Hash, which is `Marshal.dump`'d and `Base64.encode64`'d into a string to be sent to the browser in the `Set-Cookie` header. In addition, the session is cryptographically signed with your `Rails.application.config.secret_token`, which you can find in `config/initializers/secret_token.rb`.

Anyone can *read* the session state, including the `flash` Hash. But it would be impossible to forge it (unless the attacker had the key). However, there is no protection against replay attacks on the session state (where the attacker uses a session cookie he has seen before and that contains the value he wants to send to the server now).

If the replay attack is problem, or if the ability of users to *read* the session state is a problem, you should use the AR session store or, possibly a better idea, use a Redis session store. Redis is a fast key-value store whose specific use-case vs. other key-value stores includes storing session state.

Comment: good point about the replay attacks, must people don't pay attention to it. You should avoid using the session hashes as variables which change your system's state.

Comment: This answer is outdated now, correct? I was under the impression that Rails now stores session data server-side by default, and just uses the session cookie to store a unique ID for each session.

Comment: The default session store remains cookies in Rails 4, because server-side as a default would be nonsense. However, the cookie store for session state is encrypted by default in Rails 4, rendering the session state neither readable nor forgeable by anyone without the key.

Answer (score 2):

The **FlashHash** is saved and loaded in `session["flash"]` ([github](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb#L9)). So it's security depends directly on the session store setup. The cookie-based session store is the Rails default.

- In Rails 4, depending on your `config/secrets.yml` the fallowing will apply:

  - If you only have `secret_token` set, your cookies will be signed, but **not encrypted**.
  - If you have `secret_key_base` set, your cookies **will be encrypted**.

Even if you have an encrypted cookie and a AR Session Store, or a Redis Session Store, you will always end up saving a session_id into the client's cookie, which can be copied by an attacker. Setting up a `secure` cookie under a `https://` website will make it safer.

Answer (score -1):

Rails uses encoded session, so i would be inclined to say no. Use Firebug, make requests to Rails app and have a look at the cookies :)